# Is Canadian PR decided solely on "ticking the stated boxes" (including getting the "67 points")?

Tags: canada, express-entry, pr

Is Canadian permanent residence decided solely on whether the government official can "tick all the boxes" that are publicly stated? (In US English, "put a check mark in all the boxes").

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/perm/econ/fsw/selection.asp says "If the applicant’s total score is equal to or greater than [67], the officer *will* (emphasis mine) make a positive selection decision". This suggests that the answer's yes, but that's what I need to check. (Of course, all the documents you supply also have to check out OK - e.g. police certificates with no criminal record and medical examination certificates showing good health. The link goes on to link to a page referring to these.)

To put my question in other words, if you tick all these boxes, is there still a significant chance of being denied once you've got your invitation to apply? For example, I'm currently unemployed (by choice, taking a break on savings), and want to know whether getting a job before I apply might help, even though it doesn't affect the publicly stated criteria. This is a practical decision I need to make soon. Do the officials make judgments of desirability like "someone who's been unemployed a while's undesirable"?

Naturally I'm not talking about extreme and rare cases like being on a terrorism watchlist, or Osama Bin Laden applying without having technically been convicted of a crime, so having a clean Afghani police certificate!

For other PR applicants who find this via Google, the 67 points are at http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/apply-factors.asp

Comment: To clarify, you want to know if ticking the boxes while having that qualification, is sufficient? Or are you asking about ticking the box while not having the qualification?

Comment: If by "that qualification" you mean getting the 67 points, yes, I include that as one of the publicly stated boxes the official has to tick.

Comment: I believe the "having a job" is more for those who want to go from having a work visa and currently working in Canada, to getting their PR. Just having a job offer, especially when the full process of getting the PR from scratch can take potentially years, is probably not a viable way of getting points. Personally, I got my PR without having a job lined up.

Comment: The way I understand the text you linked to, you need to get the specified 67 points before your candidacy will be considered for eligibility. So it's not because you get 67 points that you'll get accepted, but it will allow you to start to process to see if you are eligible: "the officer will make a positive selection decision, and **proceed to determining admissibility**."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the requirements for applying for Canadian Permanent Residency?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11347/what-are-the-requirements-for-applying-for-canadian-permanent-residency)