# How long does it take for the PR process to complete with a job offer and express entry profile?

Tags: working-visas, canada, resident-permit, express-entry

I have received a job offer and I have an express entry profile already created. My employer will be getting me a temporary work permit for 2 years initially. I was planning to add this job offer to my express entry profile once I land in Canada. How long will it take for me to get a PR from there?

I read conflicting things on the internet. On the welcome BC site it says,

> You have 60 days to submit your application for permanent residence. IRCC will process most complete applications in six months or less.

But on several other sites it says,

> If you are working with a Canadian employer on a temporary work permit and the employer has made you an offer for permanent employment, you may be eligible to apply for your permanent residency under the Federal Skilled Worker Program. Such an offer is referred to as arranged employment. The temporary worker will have to meet the necessary points required under the Foreign Skilled Worker Program. Points are awarded based on factors such as the applicant’s education, age, adaptability, language skills and the job offer. This process can take up to 12-18 months.

Why would it take 12-18 months? With an express entry profile that has more than the cut off, shouldn't it take 1-2 months? Because invitations are sent almost every month right? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the official processing times on [CIC's official website](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-processing-times.html)? Do you have any reason to not believe those processing times? Keep in mind that there are multiple ways one can get permanent residence. So the processing time differs depending on what kind of application you are applying. For more details, you can check my old answer [here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11347/what-are-the-requirements-for-applying-for-canadian-permanent-residency/11440#11440)

Comment: Thanks Dipen. So the bottomline is 6 months then? I need to know this time period because my mother is old and alone in my home country. When I leave for Canada, until I get her a parent visa, I need to do some arrangements for her stay in my country. That's why I'm searching for this time period.

Comment: I did check in CIC's site. But I just chose PR card, and new applicant. Straight away it said 41 days. It didn't ask about being in express entry pools or having a work permit etc. So I was confused if the information was adequate for it to say that it would take 41 days

Comment: I understand leaving your parents alone in the home country can be difficult especially when they are old ( I have been through this as well)

Comment: The PR Card option is for renewal of PR Card. I don't think that's the one you are looking for. You should be looking for Economic Immigration -> Canadian Experience Class or some other class which is relevant to you. Express Entry procedures are very quick even though they say its 6 months. Mine was processed under 3 months but YMMV

Comment: thanks a ton for sharing these information. Yes I went through the site again to check Federal Skilled Worker processing time and it seems to be 6 months. I'll take that as a worst case time then. I was worried whether it'd take more than an year. Thank you very much for the help :)